# What does "Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated" mean when ssh'ing with -X?

Tags: ssh, x11forwarding, warning

When I use `ssh -X` on my Mac (running OS X 10.6.7) to connect to my Ubuntu (11.04) box, I get the following warning:

> Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding
>   setup failed: xauth key data not
>   generated Warning: No xauth data;
>   using fake authentication data for X11
>   forwarding.

Is there something I can do to make this warning go away?  If not, can I safely ignore it?

X11 forwarding seems to work fine, though I do see this message:

> Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on
>   display "localhost:10.0".

Is that related to the warning?  (I'm guessing not.  If it's not, I'll file a new question about that.)

Comment: IS the xauth program installed on the ubuntu server ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install xauth` tells me "xauth is already the newest version"

Comment: When logged in on the ubuntu server, what is the output of 'which xauth' ?

Comment: Indeed I think you should read this explanation: http://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin-xfree@cygwin.com/msg17927.html … you can ignore this warning

Comment: occasionally this can be caused by issues w/ your ~/.Xauthority file. If you delete it, it will be re-created the next time you attempt to login.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

## Try ssh -Y

Any reason you don't want to use the `-Y` flag instead of the `-X` flag?

Quite simply, the difference between `-X` and `-Y` is that [`-Y` enables trusted X11 forwarding.](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/openssh-client/ssh.1.en.html#Y)

Comment: No, I just wasn't aware of the -Y flag when I wrote the question. I believe that did turn out to be a solution. Change your answer so it's not a question (and it would be nice if you briefly explained the difference between -Y and -C) and I'll accept it.

Comment: is there any case when you wouldnt want to use -Y instead of -X ?

Comment: @Rooster for very old systems where -Y isn't supported I would say

Comment: Troubleshooting tip: Run "ssh -vv ..." and look for the xauth line and any error messages. You can try running the xauth line it shows directly. For mine I needed it to be something like "xauth list :0" (trusted) not "xauth -f /tmp/ssh... list :0" (untrusted). Which -Y fixed and "ForwardX11Trusted yes" in 
remote host /etc/ssh/ssh_config (or ~/.ssh/config) also fixed.

Comment: This solution also worked with Cygwin/X.

Comment: Note `-Y` does not _make_ your connection trusted or more trusted. Rather, it _requires_ it to be trusted _before_ you use the option. `-Y` makes ssh drop some tampering protection that it will provide when you use `-X`.

Comment: Two factor auth administered by linux side, with client side macbook seems to suddenly require `-Y` wheras in the past, either by cheese shoppian edict from apple HQ devs: before, and without two factor auth, `-X` works fine and without warning.

Answer (score 38):

**BEWARE** (tired of reading incomplete answers which lead to security flaw)

1. using ssh -Y means here having fake xauth information which is bad!
2. ssh -X should work since XQuartz, once enabled, uses xauth. The only problem is that ssh is looking for xauth in /usr/X11R6/bin and on macos with XQuartz it is in /opt/X11/bin

**Secure solving:**

1. Enable the first option in *Security* tab of preferences (Cmd-,)
   which enables authenticated connections
2. add the following to  `$HOME/.ssh/config`

   `XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth`
3. `ssh -X you_server` works in a secure maner

Comment: Works for me today with macOS Big Sur 11.6, xquartz 2.8.1 installed through homebrew. Thanks!

Comment: I have my home directory in a git repository so I don't want to add it to my `$HOME/.ssh/config`.  I've been adding it to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` but with each update it gets clobbered.  I discovered `etc/ssh/ssh_config.d` which is empty.  I added a file and put this line in that file.  It works.  I hope it doesn't get clobbered with an update.

Answer (score 25):

If you're coming here in 2015: even if everything else is set up properly, this can also happen on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite, when using `ssh -X` and running an XQuartz version <= 2.7.7. The root cause is X11 display sockets getting written outside of the xauth search path: issue [#2068](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/ticket/2068) in the XQuartz tracker.

Edit: A fixed XQuartz has since been released at the new homepage, [xquartz.org](https://www.xquartz.org/), and installing the latest version from there (currently 2.7.9) will work around the issue.

Comment: Thank you! I had *no idea* that the XQuartz I *just* downloaded from the top of the XQuartz page is not actually the latest release.

Comment: Worth noting that `brew install xquartz` presently installs the out of date 2.7.7 version.

Comment: `brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz` should get you the latest XQuartz with HomeBrew

Comment: Or shorter `brew cask install xquartz`.

Comment: omg finally after 5 years I'm back wtih a new version of XQuartz! they said they'd never update it... why Apple doesn't pay it the respect it deserves is beyond me.

Comment: I'm coming here from 2021, I implore you: get off the planet! 2021 Earth is crazy, friend.

Answer (score 19):

"Untrusted" in this context means you don't trust the connection. SSH will use additional security measures to try to make X11 forwarding safer.
"Trusted" means you are entirely confident that no on on the remote host will get access to your Xauth data and use it to monitor your keystrokes for instance.

This terminology actually confused me for years. I thought "Trusted" connections were safer. But actually it's an option you're supposed to use in situations where the connection IS trustworthy and you want to run stuff without extra security measures getting in your way. "Untrusted" is the one that makes it (somewhat) safer to deal with an untrusted remote host.

An "Untrusted" connection attempts to limit what a black hat could do to you by engaging the X11 security extension and disabling other extensions that you (hopefully) don't need. This is probably why RandR is disabled with -X. Do you need to be able to rotate your X display from the remote host?

It's also important to note that "untrusted" X11 forwarding turns off after a certain amount of time to keep you from accidentally leaving it on. New attempts to open windows will just fail after that. That bit me several times before I read enough docs to understand what was happening.

Answer (score 18):

If you get the same message even when using `-Y`, the `xauth` program might be missing on the server.  On Debian-like systems, you need the `xauth` package. On RedHat-like systems, you need the `xorg-x11-xauth` package.

Answer (score 14):

## Rule out server-side problems

First, you should rule out any server-side problems. Are you able to `ssh -X` from any other host successfully? Does `ssh -Y` work while `ssh -X` doesn't? In either case, assume ssh + X11 is set up correctly on your server and move on to the next section.

If you aren't in a position to check that (you have but your one laptop running X11, say), you can `ssh` from the server to itself using a fake session:

1. `export DISPLAY=:44` # (Bourne shell) or 
   `setenv DISPLAY :44` # (csh / tcsh)
2. `xauth add $DISPLAY MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 1234`  # Bogus cookie just for this test
3. `ssh -X localhost env |grep DISPLAY`

Expected result: there should be a DISPLAY variable set on the remote end of the ssh-to-self session. If you get no result, your server is likely mis-configured (e.g. the X11 libraries and/or the `xauth` command could be missing; or the sshd configuration could be set to deny X11 access)

## On Mac: check that Xquartz is up-to-date

As per [Will Angley's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/691761/109290)

## Examine `ssh -vv -X` output

The error message you cite is a symptom that can have many causes. Try again with `ssh -X -vv remotehost`, which should give you additional clues as to why the X11 tunnel setup failed.

Do you see the following message appearing?

```
debug1: No xauth program.
```

If so,

1. Take note of where on your client system, the `xauth` command resides:

   ```
   which xauth
   ```
2. Add the following at the very end of your ~/.ssh/config (and add a comment to remind yourself to keep it there in the future):

   ```
   Host *
       XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
   ```

   Adjust this path as per findings of step 1 — [Credits to Jan-Willem Arnold](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6825969?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 9):

I don't have a setup that can exhibit this behavior, so this is a shot in the dark:

The warning might be suppressed if you set `ForwardX11Trusted` to `"no"` for hosts that give this warning. You can place this in either `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, and you can make the option specific to a particular host by including `Host <hostname>` on the line above. the `<hostname>` component matches what you type on the command line (not the resolved hostname), and it can include wildcards.

Comment: One can use `ssh -Y` to do trusted X11 forwarding but how can one fix the untrusted one?

Comment: I got the same error in Redhat and now I'm able to solve it by editing the config file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` at client side. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

If installing `xauth` does not work right, one particularly annoying case could be a corrupted `.Xauthority` file. This particular case allowed some X clients to work, but not others with a greater tendency to fail with newer displays. Removing and recreating the `.Xauthority` file can solve that problem.

Answer (score 6):

As has already been explained above, the following worked for me:

Edit **~/.ssh/config** to add the lines

```
Host *
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

and now **ssh -X hostname** works (XQuartz 2.7.11, macOS 10.4 Mojave)

Answer (score 1):

Using XQuartz 2.7.11 on MacOS Catalina, I had to update my /etc/ssh/ssh_config file and add `XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth` after `Host *` for ssh -X to work

Answer (score 0):

I already had the latest XQuartz 2.7.11 installed, but I think I've also updated the OS a few times since then.  I reinstalled XQuartz 2.7.11, and now it is working fine.

Answer (score -3):

xauth add `hostname`/unix:10 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 `openssl rand -hex 16`

Comment: I don't understand ...